# How to search a word from a string resource file

Tags: android, android-resources, android-search

I want to search for special word in the a string resource file. I have a string resources file that contains too many topics in the form of paragraph. I know its not a good practice, It should be saved in the Database so that searching should be performed thorough that way which is very easy. But sadly the code of application I cant change, the string resource file contains too many topics and we have to search for specific term.

for your example I have a the following strings saves in string .xml

```
 <resources>
    <string name="rainbow">rainbow has seven colors. It comes after the rain. I have seen rainbow many times.</string>
<string name="computer">I have a computer in my home. I love to spend time on computer. I use computer to play games to read books and to do some surfing on internet</string>
</resources>
```

so for your example I have pasted two little paragraph.

Now for example I want to search word "games" which is used in second para having id of computer, and also i can search any word in the string file.

> So here is what I want :

1. I want to know is that possible to search any word in the string resource file?

2.If Yes then how can I show the list of strings that contain the words that I searched ?

Please tell me the way to search for a word in the specific resource file and also tell me or guide me the way I can implement to search and enlisting all those topics name that has that word that is searched . thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a string array in strings file and get that array in java file and then do your searching as you wish

Comment: @VivekMishra in this way I would only be searching the topics name , I want to search a word even in the body of topic

Comment: you can see I have topic name in string resources , Named , Computer , I want to get this name "computer" because it contain the word books.
Books is the word that I wanted to search Moreover I want to enlist all those strings that contains this word "books"

Comment: i think making the array would not help you